# Safari iOS8 using more data because of cross domain cache

Tags: safari, ios8, mobile-safari

I was doing some debugging using Fiddler and I noticed that css/js/any resource that's requested isn't cached between domains even if they're requesting the exact same thing. For example the Facebook like button is loaded every time you visit a new website with it.  Am I correct with my analysis that iOS Safari uses more data than previous versions?